# Created an AddEventListener with two functions for a button. Only one of the two functions are working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an event listener that then you click on the button, two actions occur:

1. The progress bar updates (which it does already)
2. The text inside the p tags are displayed below the progress bar and change with each click as well. So With 25% I want to show "Step 1", for 50% I want to show "Step 2", for 75% show "Step 3" and 100%, show "step 4".

Right now, the only thing updating is the progress bar.  The feature is not breaking, but the p tags are not displaying.  Was wondering if any one can show me what I am doing wrong and see if there is a possible solution.

The approach I took was from another example I saw on SO.
I created a function called textExample where I thought I was creating an array  and then looping through it and then displaying the text by creating another eventlistener and then passing a callback function.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('#next')
btn.addEventListener("click", move)
var width = 25;

function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  if (width < 100) {
    width += 25;
    elem.style.width = width + '%';
    elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
  }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", textExample)


function textExample() {
  const p_array = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  const count = p_array.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const p = p_array[i];

    p.addEventListener("click", function() {
      document.getElementByClassName("tab").innerHTML = p.dataset.value
    })
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: orangered;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.tab {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container">

    <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="background:orangered">Upload file</button> -->
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center">
            <img style="width:90%; height:90%; align;" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png">
            <div style="margin-top: 15px;">
              <div id="myProgress">
                <div id="myBar">25%</div>
              </div>
              <div class="tab">
                <p data-value="One">Step 1</p>
              </div>
              <div class="tab">
                <p data-value="Two">Step 2</p>
              </div>
              <div class="tab">
                <p data-value="Three">Step 3</p>
              </div>
              <div class="tab">
                <p data-value="Four">Step 4</p>
              </div>

            </div>
            <button id="next">Next</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It is displaying for me on eachclick 25% , 50% , 75%, 100%

Comment: `getElementByClassName()` returns a collection that you need to iterate the same way you are doing with `getElementsByTagName`. Really bad practice adding event listeners inside other event handlers

Comment: @Carlos1232 I am looking to display the text inside of the p tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your tabs have `display: none;`, so you will have to add `display: block;` through inline styling in order to reveal them. Also, you can simplify the answer by cycling through an array containing all of the tabs.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('#next')
btn.addEventListener("click", move)
const p_array = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');

let current = 0;

var width = 25;

p_array[current].style.display = 'block';

function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  if (width < 100) {
    p_array[current].style.removeProperty('display');
    p_array[++current].style.display = 'block';
    width += 25;
    elem.style.width = width + '%';
    elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: orangered;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.tab {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container">

    <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="background:orangered">Upload file</button> -->
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center">
            <img style="width:90%; height:90%; align;" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png">
            <div style="margin-top: 15px;">
              <div id="myProgress">
                <div id="myBar">25%</div>
              </div>
              <div class="tab">
                <p data-value="One">Step 1</p>
              </div>
              <div class="tab">
                <p data-value="Two">Step 2</p>
              </div>
              <div class="tab">
                <p data-value="Three">Step 3</p>
              </div>
              <div class="tab">
                <p data-value="Four">Step 4</p>
              </div>

            </div>
            <button id="next">Next</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```